# Activating Compression (esp. Dynamic Compression) with IIS-Express

Tags: compression, iis-express

Is it somehow possible to enable dynamic compression (for WCF-Services) on an IIS-Express?

It's a development environment issue so I cannot use the full version: but I need to figure out how it would behave with compression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the configfile in Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config: here in the httpCompression-Section you can define the mime-types to use for dynamic compression.

Answer (score 10):

Go to IIS Express installation folder (%programfiles%\IIS Express) and run the following command to enable dynamic compression.

```
appcmd set config -section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:true
```

Then add mime-types. Run following commands to add wildcard entries or take a look at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression to add specific mime-types

```
 appcmd set config /section:httpCompression /staticTypes.[mimeType='*/*'].enabled:"true" /commit:apphost

  appcmd set config /section:httpCompression /dynamicTypes.[mimeType='*/*'].enabled:"true" /commit:apphost
```

Comment: Thx for the hint: but this was not exactly what I wanted. Meanwhile I found the configFile where to set that: its in Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config in the section httpCompression: there I can define the types for dynamic compression.