# Enable gzip compression using MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip, http-compression

I am using the chrome extension YSlow to test my site performance.

I've got F Grade on Compress components with gzip.

There are 15 plain text components that should be sent compressed:

```
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/blog.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/style.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/socialize-bookmarks.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/prettyPhoto.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/flexslider.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/css/colors/color-orange.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/sc2.css
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/custom.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/header.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/twitter.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/bra.photostream.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/jquery.flexslider.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js
http://localhost:21964/Content/custom/javascript/prettyPhoto.js
http://localhost:21964/css/colors/color-orange.css
```

Compression reduces response times by reducing the size of the HTTP response. Gzip is the most popular and effective compression method currently available and generally reduces the response size by about 70%. Approximately 90% of today's Internet traffic travels through browsers that claim to support gzip.

There was a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992524/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-when-using-mvc3-on-iis7), But even though I've followed these steps it doesn't compress the traffic.

Steps I've done:

1. I ticked all the compression settings in the IIS -> Compression.
2. Activate the Windows Feature "Dynamic Content Compression".
3. I've added this lines to the `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
...
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
   <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
   <dynamicTypes>
     <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
   </dynamicTypes>
   <staticTypes>
     <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
     <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
   </staticTypes>
 </httpCompression>
 <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" /> 
...
</system.webServer>
```

I am currently using the Developer Server inside the project Properties -> Web -> Servers

Answer (score 2):

The visual studio development server (Cassini) doesn't support gzip compression use IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: I changed to IIS Express and set the dynamic and static compression by the appcmd, and validated that its configuration file was updated and it did, but still it doesn't compress :/

By the way I used whats written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572702/activating-compression-esp-dynamic-compression-with-iis-express